# How to handle number input in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is how a regular input field would be handled in react/typescript where `value` is type string:

```
const [value, onChange] = useState<string>('');

const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  setValue(e.target.value);
}

return (
  <input
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);
```

But I'm having trouble where my input is of type number:

```
const [value, onChange] = useState<number>();

const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  // type error
  setValue(e.target.value);
}

return (
  <input
    type="number"
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);
```

in this case, value is of type number, input is of type number (so hypothetically `e.target.value` should always be of type number. However according to typescript, `event.target.value` is always a string. I can cast it to number ie.

```
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  setValue(Number(e.target.value));
}
```

but now if some number is typed in and the user backspaces it to make it empty, the value changes to 0 - the field can never be empty.

keeping value as string and then casting it to number on save is not a viable solution

something i'm temporarily doing is making `e.target.value` as any:

```
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  setValue(e.target.value as any);
}
```

which works great but am I missing something to keep this type safe?

Answer (score 15):

In general, you'll want to make your variable a string for everything to work well.

Then when you want to use it as a number, convert it at that point. You can easily convert it to a number using something like `+value` or `parseFloat(value)`

The input uses a string type for a reason. And this way you keep the typesafety that typescript provides.

Many people suggest avoiding the number input altogether for various reasons:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/26/why-the-number-input-is-the-worst-input/

https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/

---

If you want to keep the data for the number input as a number, you can use the suggestion from Loïc Goyet's answer:

```
const [value, onChange] = useState<number|null>(null);

const onNumberChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  // In general, use Number.isNaN over global isNaN as isNaN will coerce the value to a number first
  // which likely isn't desired
  const value = !Number.isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber) ? e.target.valueAsNumber : null;

  setValue(value);
}

return (
  <input
    type="number"
    value={value ?? ''}
    onChange={onNumberChange}
  />
);
```

This works as it does specifically because number inputs are a bit weird in how they work. If the input is valid, then the `value` and by extension `valueAsNumber` will be defined, otherwise `value` will be an empty string `''`.

You can use that with the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) to apply the empty string whenever you don't have a value, so that your state can be `number|null` instead of `number|string` or even `number|undefined` if you set your values that way. It's important to use `??` instead of `||` as `0` is a [`falsy` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JS! Otherwise you'll prevent the user from typing in `0`. This is similar to why the value kept changing to `0` for the OP. [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_coercion) has some potentially unexpected behavior for some inputs, it appears to
treat most falsy values as either `0` or `NaN`.

This will *only* work with the `type="number"` inputs, due to the way the browser and react treats them. Doing it this way instead of the way above will break if the browser doesn't support `type="number"` inputs, in which case it falls back to `type="text"`.

You will also lose the information about how the user entered the data if that is relevant to you: e.g. `1e2` vs `100`.

Comment: Would you say that all these values should be stored in the DB as `string`s too? So they're only converted in the application when it needs the `number` type (for example, to calculate something).

Comment: They shouldn't be. When you send the value to the backend, you should validate the results and ensure it's a valid number for your use case. You can do the parsing on the FE with a schema based validator like yup, zod, or others. You can and should still make sure the data is properly validated in the BE to prevent malicious inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to cast! You can simply reuse information held into the event!

The `target` property from the event object has a `valueAsNumber` property for every kind of inputs element which returns the value typed as number. Even if it's not a `type="number"`, and so the `valueAsNumber` equals `NaN`.

Also from the `target` has a `type` property which will be equal to the HTML's `type` attribute on your input target.

So combining those two properties, you could do :

```
const value = e.target.type === "number" && !isNaN(e.target.valueAsNumber) ? e.target.valueAsNumber : e.target.value

setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem, this is how I solved it.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string | number>('');

const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
   setValue(+e.target.value);
}

return (
  <input
    type="number"
    value={value === 0 ? '' : value}
    onChange={handleChange}
 />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML input="number" spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type%3Dnumber)) for reference. From the spec:

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty string instead.

I used this information to build a similar implementation, but testing `value === ''` to know when the value didn't parse as a valid number.

Here's a full implementation in React/TS:

```js
import React, { ChangeEventHandler, useState } from 'react';

// NumberInput component
interface INumberInput {
  onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined;
  value: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined;
}

const NumberInput = ({ onChange, value }: INumberInput) => {
  return (
    <input
      onChange={onChange}
      type="number"
      value={value ?? ''} // prevent React error "...switch from uncontrolled to controlled..."
    />
  );
};

const TestNumberInput = () => {
  // State
  const [numberValue, setNumberValue] = useState<number>();

  // onChange handler
  const handleChangeNumber =
    (setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | undefined>>) =>
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      const valueAsNumber = event.target.valueAsNumber;
      console.log('value:', value);
      console.log('valueAsNumber:', valueAsNumber);

      // A number input field, i.e. <input type="number" /> returns an empty string when the
      // input does not parse as a number, so set the state to undefined in this case.
      if (value === '') {
        console.log('setting number value to undefined');
        setState(undefined);
      } else {
        console.log('setting number value:', valueAsNumber);
        setState(valueAsNumber);
      }
    };

  return <NumberInput onChange={handleChangeNumber(setNumberValue)} value={numberValue} />;
};

export default TestNumberInput;
```

I prefer `undefined` to `null`, as the I find the state more readable, and the expected type of value on the HTML input component is `string | number | readonly string[] | undefined`. I added the `console.log()` statements so you can see what's happening as well as illustrate one caveat.

The caveat to both my answer and the `isNaN` / `valueAsNumber` approach is that a number ending in a decimal is not a valid number. Thus, you'll see upon entering `12.` that `value` will be `''` and `valueAsNumber` will be `isNaN`. Adding another number after the decimal will return the value to a number.

Answer (score -1):

When you set `type="number"`, there are 3 things you should be aware of:

1- type of input will be `string`. `console.log(typeof event.target.value)`

2- If you type a number less than 10, if you `console.log(event.target.value`, it will log 01,02,03

3- you wont be able to delete 0 from the input. In order to add 11, you need to manually bring the cursor to the beginning of input and then type the value.

- Solve using `parseInt`

  ```
  //typescript will infer value as number
  const [value, onChange] = useState(0);
  ```

inside `onChange`

```
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    // if you want decimal use parseFloat
    // if you delete 0 and pass "" to parseInt you get NaN
    const value = parseInt(e.target.value) || 0;
    setValue(value);
  }
```

to prevent the 3rd issue in `input` element

```
   <input
      // if you see 0 just put "" instead
      value={value || ""}
      onChange={onChange}
      type="number"
    />
```

- Solve using `Number`

  const [value, onChange] = useState(0);

in `onChange`

```
 const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const val = Number(e.target.value)
    if (Number.isInteger(val) && val >= 0) {
      setValue(val)
    }
  }

  <input
      // if you see 0 just put "" instead
      value={value || ""}
      onChange={onChange}
      type="number"
    />
```

You could also set it as type `string` but eventually if you needed to do some arithmetic operations, you have to use one of the above methods to convert it to a number